# Have my asp:DropDownList slide down when selected and NOT sliding both up and down

Tags: html, asp.net

been looking for a similar issue for a moment but couldn't find anything about that anywhere.

Working on an ASP.NET project and I need my asp:DropDownList to have it's elements sliding DOWN when selected.

When the selected item is the first one, everything is OK since I'm at the top of my element list, but if I select the dropdownlist when the selected item is like the XXth, the list will be displayed with a slide going up and down at the same time (that makes my currently selected item in the middle of the displayed list).

I want my list to be sliding down always, whatever my selected element position is (the same display as if the selected element was always the 1st).

Hope my question is clear.

If you need any screen, I'll send you some but it's probably not necessary.

Thanks by advance for your answers !

Comment: I don't fully understand. So when a user selects something from your DropDownList in the middle of the list, you want that selection to become the first item in your DropDownList so that a user can only scroll downwards?

Comment: Nope, i don't want the item to become the first item, I want my list to act AS IF the selection was the first item (So that the list would open sliding downwards ONLY and not Upwards AT THE SAME TIME). I hope it's clearer now =) (Edit: Recreating a Dropdownlist with this item as the first element would be a solution ... but that's not exactly what I want here).